# How to get the most duplicate after counting a string column using query in google sheet

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have a list of cites (duplicated) in google sheet, I want to use count and group by functions and then get the most duplicated city (maybe the first three).

```
=QUERY(xx!1:9895,
 "select count(K) // k is the city col
  group by K
  order by count(K)  DESC 
  label count(K) 'Cites'");
```

I am not sure what function should I use to get the most duplicated city, I already tried max, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=query( 
  xx!K1:K,
  "select K, count(K) 
   where K is not null 
   group by K 
   order by count(K) desc 
   limit 3 
   label K 'City', count(K) 'Count' ", 
  0 
)
```